# Azure Backup for VPS

Tags: azure, server, backup, vps

I have a windows VPS, not on azure. I'm looking into the Azure backup services.

Ideally I'd like to backup the whole VPS to azure. Lets say MY current VPS dies, then I can just use the Azure backup to create a new VPS, with all programs, settings, files, databases everything.

I'm not sure which of the azure options to pick for this:

[image]

Does anyone know any good resources or what each of the options mean, or have any suggestions? I've read lots on the Azure website but it's not particularly clear.

Apologies if this is basic stuff or I've missed an obvious resource, I'm new to servers.

Many thanks,

Phil.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to have a full backup of your machine choosing 'files and folders' and 'system state' is your best option:

- Files and folders will allow you to recover individual files and folders on your machine. Imagine a user accidentally deletes a file, you can recover it from the backup.
- System State will allow you to recover your system state (configuration of your machine) if your machine would be corrupted.
- The other items in there will allow you to recover from specific sources (Hyper-V or VMware) or to take application consistent back-ups.

To recover a full machine, I would enable files/folders and system state backup. With Azure Backup you can restore either on Azure (on a VM on Azure) or on the source server.

Make sure to also have a look at Azure Site Recovery. With Azure Site Recovery, you can 'mirror' a machine towards Azure. This will allow you to very quickly restore a machine in case of corruption on Azure. If your source is a VPS, you would only be able to restore to Azure with site recovery, not go back to the VPS.